# Call the (undefined) rest of an array somewhere

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, undefined, call

How could I call the rest of my array at the end of my string ? I heard about spread operator (but I am not really sure). Indeed, the number of index that I got from my array is uncertain (except for the two first).

```
let filePath = "folder/folder/potentialFolder/potentialFolder/.../file.txt";
let filePathBackup = filePath.split('/');
filePathBackup = `${filePathBackup[0]}/${filePathBackup[1]}/backup/${the_rest_of_my_array}`;
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: is `filePath` supposed to be a string?

Comment: Use `filePath.join('/')`

Comment: Yeah, it is edited. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.slice()` and `.join()` like this:

```
let filePath = 'folder/folder/potentialFolder/potentialFolder/.../file.txt';
let filePathBackup = filePath.split('/');
let rest = filePathBackup.slice(2).join('/');
let result = ${filePathBackup[0]}/${filePathBackup[1]}/backup/${rest}`;
```